# How to turn on port 443 in WHM for VA test

Tags: security, webserver, port, cpanel, whm

I have build website for one of my clients and now client going to make a VA test from a 3rd party. They asked me to open the **port 443** in my web server. By the way I can not find the port settings on my WHM panel. Can anybody tell me how to turn on the **port 443** in WHM or Cpanel please ??

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed CSF on your WHM server then you can follow their article
https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/8754122593559-How-to-open-a-port-with-CSF-in-WHM

You need to add port 443 to incoming traffic.